# Strange (?) result from the BVD for a Dafny program

Tags: dafny

When I verify the following program fragment which has an off-by one error in it,
[image: a Dafny method reproduced below]

I get the following result from the BVD, which I don't understand.

[image: BVD result]

The thing that puzzles me is that the second invariant seems to have been ignored in generating the counterexample.  If the two invariants are I0 and I1 and the guard is G, then surely the verification condition is 
    I0 && I1 && !G ==> qy > x
and a counterexample should satisfy the negation of this.  What have I misunderstood?

---

The code is reproduced below for the convenience of anyone who wants it.

```
function TwoToThe( i : int ) : int
decreases i 
requires i >= 0
{
    if i==0 then 1 else 2*TwoToThe( i-1 )
}

method interestingBVD(x : int, y : int)
    requires y > 0 
    requires x >= 0
{
    var q := 1 ;
    var qy := y ; // Tracks q*y
    ghost var i := 0 ;
    // Double q until q*y exceeds x
    while( qy < x )  // Off by one error.
        invariant qy == q*y
        invariant q == TwoToThe(i)
        decreases 2*x-qy ;
    {
        q, qy, i := 2*q, 2*qy, i + 1 ;
    }
    // In the BVD we get actual numbers!!
    assert q*y == qy > x && q == TwoToThe(i) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verification Debugger is pointing out that `qy` might equal `x`, and in particular that they may both be `2988`. Indeed, `!G` in your comment is `x <= qy`, not `qy > x`.

While we're on this example, there's another noteworthy issue:

From the second invariant, the verifier does know `q == TwoToThe(i)`. This is expected and can be tested using an `assert`, as you have done. Stated differently, the verifier knows that `q` equals the result of applying `TwoToThe` to `i`. The Verification Debugger shows `q` and `i` to have the values `2988` and `5330`. This may seem odd, since *we* know that `TwoToThe(5330)` is far greater than `2988`. So, what's going on here?

To figure out the value of `TwoToThe(5330)`, one has to unfold the definition of `TwoToThe` 5330 times. The verifier doesn't try to unfold the definition that many times, so `2988` still appears a plausible value of `TwoToThe(5330)`, as far as it can tell. This can be useful information when debugging a failed verification.

In conclusion, the Verification Debugger provides insight into The World According the Verifier, that is, insight into what the verifier is "thinking". Here, we can see it "thinks" `TwoToThe(5330)` returns `2988`. We, then, in turn, learn that either the definition of `TwoToThe` is not what its name suggests or the verifier is not fully expanding the thousands of recursive calls of `TwoToThe` needed to determine the value.

Rustan